# How can this C++ json library be improved

Tags: c++, parsing, json

I need a class to generate json content from data retrieved from a database.  This gave me an excuse to play at creating a json library.  This is my first attempt so it could probably be improved in many ways.

Features are:

1. feed in json from stdin to populate internal structures.
2. output json to stdout.
3. insert into json.
4. find by json key name.

It uses std::variant which requires c++17 or better.

Please review the code and give me some feedback.

Is it heading in the right direction?

Firstly the main header, json20.hpp:

```
#ifndef JSON20_HPP_
#define JSON20_HPP_

#include <variant>  // type-safe union
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

#include "json_value.hpp"

struct json_array {
    std::vector<json_value> array;
};

struct json_object {
    std::map < std::string, json_value> object;

    json_value& operator [](std::string key) {
        return object[key];
    }
};

struct json_null {

};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const json_value& v);


class json20 {
public:
    /* start empty constructor */
    json20() {}

    /* construct json object from input stream */
    json20(std::istream& istrm, std::string& parse_status);

    /* parent node of json object */
    json_value root;

    /* insert json object by manual construction. Returns true on successful insertion */
    bool insert(const json_object& object);

    /* find json value by key name */
    bool find_by_key(const std::string& key_name, json_value& value);

private:
    bool parse(std::istream& istrm, std::string& parse_status);
    json_value parse_json(std::istream& istrm, json_value& value, std::string& parse_status);
    bool recursive_find_by_key(const std::string& key_name, json_object& next, json_value& value);
};

#endif // JSON20_HPP_
```

json values header, json_value.hpp:

```
#ifndef JSON_VALUE_HPP_
#define JSON_VALUE_HPP_

#include "json20.hpp"

#include <variant>
#include <string>

// fwd declare
struct json_array;
struct json_object;
struct json_null;

typedef std::variant<double, bool, std::string, json_array, json_object, json_null> json_value;

#endif // JSON_VALUE_HPP_
```

json implementation file, json20.cpp:

```
#include "json20.hpp"

#include <cstring>

static void eat_whitespace(std::istream& istrm) {
    int ch;
    while (istrm) {
        ch = istrm.peek();
        if (isspace(ch)) {
            istrm.get();
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

static char get_next_token(std::istream& istrm) {
    eat_whitespace(istrm);
    char ch;
    if (istrm.get(ch))
        return ch;
    else
        return (char)-1;  // indicate failure;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const json_value& v) {

    switch (v.index()) {
    case 0:
        os << std::get<0>(v);
        break;
    case 1:
        if (std::get<1>(v)) {
            os << "true";
        }
        else {
            os << "false";
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        os << '"' << std::get<2>(v) << '"';
        break;
    case 3:
    {
        os << '[';
        bool first = true;
        json_array arr = std::get<json_array>(v);
        for (auto& item : arr.array) {
            if (!first) {
                os << ',';
            }
            os << item;
            first = false;
        }

        os << ']';
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        os << '{';
        bool first = true;
        json_object obj = std::get<json_object>(v);
        for (auto& item : obj.object) {
            if (!first) {
                os << ',';
            }
            os << '"' << item.first << "\":";
            os << item.second;
            first = false;
        }

        os << '}';
        break;
    }
    case 5:
        os << "null";
        break;
    }

    return os;
}

static bool try_string(std::istream& istrm, json_value& value) {
    eat_whitespace(istrm);
    char ch = static_cast<char>(istrm.peek());
    if (ch != '"') {
        return false;
    }

    // remove first "
    istrm.get(ch);

    std::string s;
    while (istrm.get(ch)) {
        if (ch == '"') {
            value.emplace<2>(s);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            // haven't worked out how to just append ch to end of string in value
            s += ch;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

static bool try_number(std::istream& istrm, json_value& value) {

    eat_whitespace(istrm);
    char ch = static_cast<char>(istrm.peek());
    if (ch != '-' && !isdigit(ch)) {
        return false;
    }

    while (istrm.get(ch)) {
        // start of a number
        if (ch == '-' || (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')) {
            char buf[10] = {};
            buf[0] = ch;
            int i = 1;
            while (istrm.get(ch)) {
                if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' || ch == '.') {
                    buf[i] = ch;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    istrm.putback(ch);
                    break;
                }
            }
            double number = strtod(buf, nullptr);
            value.emplace<0>(number);
            return true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            istrm.putback(ch);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

static bool check_bytes(std::istream& istrm, const char* expected) {
    const size_t length(strlen(expected));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char ch;
        if(!istrm.get(ch)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (ch != expected[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

static bool try_boolean(std::istream& istrm, json_value& value, std::string& parse_status) {

    eat_whitespace(istrm);
    char ch = static_cast<char>(istrm.peek());
    if (ch != 'f' && ch != 't') {
        return false;
    }

    if (ch == 'f') {
        const char* expected = "false";
        if (check_bytes(istrm, expected)) {
            value.emplace<bool>(false);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            parse_status += "parse of boolean false value failed|";
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (ch == 't') {
        const char* expected = "true";
        if (check_bytes(istrm, expected)) {
            value.emplace<bool>(true);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            parse_status += "parse of boolean true value failed|";
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

static bool try_null(std::istream& istrm, json_value& value, std::string& parse_status) {

    eat_whitespace(istrm);
    char ch = static_cast<char>(istrm.peek());
    if (ch != 'n') {
        return false;
    } else {
        const char* expected = "null";
        if (check_bytes(istrm, expected)) {
            value.emplace<json_null>();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            parse_status += "parse of null value failed|";
            return false;
        }
    }
}

json20::json20(std::istream& istrm, std::string& parse_status) {
    parse(istrm, parse_status);
}

json_value json20::parse_json(std::istream& istrm, json_value& value, std::string& parse_status) {

    if (try_number(istrm, value)) {
        return value;
    }

    if (try_string(istrm, value)) {
        return value;
    }

    if (try_boolean(istrm, value, parse_status)) {
        return value;
    }

    if (try_null(istrm, value, parse_status)) {
        return value;
    }

    char ch = get_next_token(istrm);
    if (ch == '{') {

        json_object object;
        ch = get_next_token(istrm);
        if (ch == '}') {
            return object;
        }

        while (istrm) {
            if (ch == '"') {
                istrm.putback(ch);
                std::string key;
                json_value kvalue;

                if (!try_string(istrm, kvalue)) {
                    parse_status += "unexpected json parsing failure of name|";
                    return kvalue;
                }
                else {
                    key = std::get<2>(kvalue);
                }

                ch = get_next_token(istrm);
                if (ch != ':') {
                    parse_status += "encountered an unexpected symbol: ";
                    parse_status += ch;
                    parse_status += ", : was expected|";

                }

                object[key] = parse_json(istrm, value, parse_status);

                ch = get_next_token(istrm);
                if (ch == '}') {
                    return object;
                }

                if (ch != ',') {
                    parse_status += "encountered an unexpected symbol: ";
                    parse_status += ch;
                    parse_status += " , (comma) was expected|";
                    return object;
                }

                ch = get_next_token(istrm);
            }
            else {
                parse_status += "encountered an unexpected symbol: ";
                parse_status += ch;
                parse_status += " , \" (quote) was expected|";
                return object;
            }
        }
    }

    if (ch == '[') {
        json_array jarray;
        ch = get_next_token(istrm);
        if (ch == ']') {
            return jarray;
        }
        istrm.putback(ch);
        while (istrm) {
            jarray.array.push_back(parse_json(istrm, value, parse_status));
            ch = get_next_token(istrm);
            if (ch == ']') {
                break;
            }
            if (ch != ',') {
                parse_status += "comma expected, instead saw ";
                parse_status += ch;
                parse_status += '|';

            }
        }
        return jarray;
    }

    // if  get to here something is wrong
    parse_status += "parse failure, last character parsed: ";
    parse_status += ch;
    parse_status += '|';
    return value;  // no type/value will be set if return here
}

bool json20::parse(std::istream& istrm, std::string& parse_status) {

    root = parse_json(istrm, root, parse_status);

    return true;
}

bool json20::insert(const json_object& object) {

    root = object;

    return true;
}

bool json20::recursive_find_by_key(const std::string& key_name, json_object& next, json_value& value) {

    const auto found = next.object.find(key_name);
    if (found != next.object.end()) {
        value = found->second;
        return true;
    }
    // if not found, iterate over current values for child objects
    for (const auto element : next.object) {
        switch (element.second.index()) {
        case 3: // json_array
        {
            json_array jarray = std::get<json_array>(element.second);
            for (const auto list_item : jarray.array) {
                if (list_item.index() == 4) {
                    json_object child = std::get<json_object>(list_item);
                    return recursive_find_by_key(key_name, child, value);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        case 4:  // json_object
            json_object child = std::get<json_object>(element.second);
            return recursive_find_by_key(key_name, child, value);
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool json20::find_by_key(const std::string& key_name, json_value& value) {

    // root should be a json_object, but check just in case
    switch (root.index()) {
        case 4: // json_object
        {
            json_object obj = std::get<json_object>(root);
            if (recursive_find_by_key(key_name, obj, value)) {
                return true;
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

test code using gtest, test.cpp:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include "json20.hpp"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

TEST(json20, GivenEmptyJsonStringThenConstructsCorrectly) {

    std::string myjson = "{}";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;

    // take in through stdin
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    // output to stdout
    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    ostrm << json.root;

    std::string expected("{}");
    EXPECT_EQ(ostrm.str(), expected);
}

TEST(json20, GivenJsonStringUsingNullThenConstructsCorrectly) {

    std::string myjson = "{ \"myvalue\": null }";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;

    // take in through stdin
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    // output to stdout
    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    ostrm << json.root;

    std::string expected("{\"myvalue\":null}");
    EXPECT_EQ(ostrm.str(), expected);
}

TEST(json20, GivenNumberJsonStringThenConstructsCorrectly) {

    std::string myjson = "{ \"mynumber\": 3.142 }";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;

    // take in through stdin
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    // output to stdout
    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    ostrm << json.root;

    std::string expected("{\"mynumber\":3.142}");
    EXPECT_EQ(ostrm.str(), expected);
}

TEST(json20, GivenStringJsonStringThenConstructsCorrectly) {

    std::string myjson = "{ \"mystring\": \"Angus\" }";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;

    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    ostrm << json.root;

    std::string expected("{\"mystring\":\"Angus\"}");
    EXPECT_EQ(ostrm.str(), expected);
}

TEST(json20, GivenStringJsonArrayThenConstructsCorrectly) {

    std::string myjson = "{ \"myarray\": [\"Angus\", \"Lisa\"]}";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    ostrm << json.root;

    std::string expected("{\"myarray\":[\"Angus\",\"Lisa\"]}");
    EXPECT_EQ(ostrm.str(), expected);
}

TEST(json20, GivenNumberJsonArrayThenConstructsCorrectly) {

    std::string myjson = "{ \"myarray\": [1, 2, 3]}";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    ostrm << json.root;

    std::string expected("{\"myarray\":[1,2,3]}");
    EXPECT_EQ(ostrm.str(), expected);
}

TEST(json20, GivenAMixedJsonArrayThenConstructsCorrectly) {

    std::string myjson = "{ \"myarray\": [1, \"Angus\", 3]}";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    ostrm << json.root;

    std::string expected("{\"myarray\":[1,\"Angus\",3]}");
    EXPECT_EQ(ostrm.str(), expected);
}

TEST(json20, GivenMultipleJsonArraysThenConstructsCorrectly) {

    std::string myjson = "{ \"myarray\": [\"Angus\", \"Lisa\", {\"objage\": [true, 4,false]}, \"Wookie\"]}";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    ostrm << json.root;

    std::string expected("{\"myarray\":[\"Angus\",\"Lisa\",{\"objage\":[true,4,false]},\"Wookie\"]}");
    EXPECT_EQ(ostrm.str(), expected);
}


TEST(json20, GivenComplexJsonThenConstructsCorrectly) {
    std::string myjson = R"###({
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName" : "Smith",
        "isAlive" : true,
        "age" : 27,
        "address" : {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
            "city" : "New York",
            "state" : "NY",
            "postalCode" : "10021-3100"
    },
        "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "home",
                "number" : "212 555-1234"
        },
    {
        "type": "office",
        "number" : "646 555-4567"
    }
        ],
            "children": [],
            "spouse": null
})###";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    ostrm << json.root;

    std::string expected("{\"myarray\":[\"Angus\",\"Lisa\",{\"objage\":[true,4,false]},\"Wookie\"]}");
}


// failed cases
TEST(json20, GivenEmptyStringThenConstructsCorrectly) {

    std::string myjson;  // blank string

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;

    // take in through stdin
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    // output to stdout
    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    ostrm << json.root;

    std::string expected("");
    EXPECT_NE(error.size(), 0u);
}

TEST(json20, GivenInvalidUnquotedStringValueJsonStringThenNoCrash) {

    std::string myjson = "{ \"mynumber\":unquoted string }";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;

    // take in through stdin
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    // output to stdout
    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    ostrm << json.root;

    EXPECT_NE(error.size(), 0u);
}

TEST(json20, GivenLargeButInvalidJsonStringThenNoCrash) {

    std::string myjson = R"###({
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName" -- "Smith",
        "isAlive" : true,
        "age" : 27,
        "address" : {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
            "city" : "New York",
            "state" : "NY",
            "postalCode" : "10021-3100"
    },
        "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "home",
                "number" : "212 555-1234"
        },
    {
        "type": "office",
        "number" : 646 555-4567
    }
        ],
            "children": [[[],
            "spouse": nill
})###";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;

    // take in through stdin
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    // output to stdout
    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    ostrm << json.root;

    EXPECT_NE(error.size(), 0u);
}

TEST(json20, GivenAJsonObjectThenOutputAsExpected) {

    const std::string s = "my list";
    double arrayofdoubles[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
    json_array jarray;
    for (auto i : arrayofdoubles) {
        jarray.array.push_back(i);
    }

    json_object obj;
    obj.object[s] = jarray;

    json20 json;
    json.insert(obj);

    //// output to stdout
    std::ostringstream ostrm;
    ostrm << json.root;

    std::string expected("{\"my list\":[1,2,3]}");
    EXPECT_EQ(ostrm.str(), expected);
}

TEST(json20, GivenValidJsonThenFindValueByKey) {
    std::string myjson = R"###({
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName" : "Smith",
        "isAlive" : true,
        "age" : 27,
        "address" : {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
            "city" : "New York",
            "state" : "NY",
            "postalCode" : "10021-3100"
    },
        "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "home",
                "number" : "212 555-1234"
        },
    {
        "type": "office",
        "number" : "646 555-4567"
    }
        ],
            "children": [],
            "spouse": null
})###";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    json_value value;
    EXPECT_TRUE(json.find_by_key("firstName", value));

    const json_value expected = std::string("John");
    EXPECT_EQ(std::get<std::string>(value), std::get<std::string>(expected));
}

TEST(json20, GivenJsonWithNestedKeyThenFindValueByKey) {
    std::string myjson = R"###({
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName" : "Smith",
        "nestedLevel1Key" : { "name": "childString1", "NestedLevel2Key": { "age": 10, "address1": "1 Woodlough Way" } }
    })###";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    json_value value;
    EXPECT_TRUE(json.find_by_key("address1", value));

    const json_value expected = std::string("1 Woodlough Way");
    EXPECT_EQ(std::get<std::string>(value), std::get<std::string>(expected));
}

TEST(json20, GivenJsonWithNestedKeyInArrayThenFindValueByKey) {
    std::string myjson = R"###({
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName" : "Smith",
        "nestedLevel1Key" : [ "age": 29, { "name": "childString1", "NestedLevel2Key": [{ "address1": "1 Woodlough Way" }] }]
    })###";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    json_value value;
    EXPECT_TRUE(json.find_by_key("address1", value));

    const json_value expected = std::string("1 Woodlough Way");
    EXPECT_EQ(std::get<std::string>(value), std::get<std::string>(expected));
}

TEST(json20, GivenInvalidbooleanJsonValueThenParseErrorShouldIndicateBooleanError) {
    std::string myjson = R"###({
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName" : "Smith",
        "isAlive" : truw,
        "age" : 27,
        "address" : {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
            "city" : "New York",
            "state" : "NY",
            "postalCode" : "10021-3100"
    },
        "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "home",
                "number" : "212 555-1234"
        },
    {
        "type": "office",
        "number" : "646 555-4567"
    }
        ],
            "children": [],
            "spouse": null
})###";

    std::stringstream iostrm;
    iostrm << myjson;
    std::string error;
    json20 json(iostrm, error);

    size_t found_error = error.find("bool");
    EXPECT_NE(error.size(), 0u);
    EXPECT_NE(found_error, std::string::npos);
}
```

Comment: Have you see this? https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer I had exactly the same issue. So I developed this. The idea was to convert to/from JSON without using an intermediate structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code Review:

I don't like this as it gives you an extra level of indirection.

```
struct json_array {
    std::vector<json_value> array;
};
```

You can simply use another name:

using json_array = std::vector;

This gives you a specific name for the array and removes the level of indirection.

---

Sure this is resonable:

```
struct json_object {
    std::map < std::string, json_value> object;
```

Note That if you try and access an element that does not exist it will add it to the object (even if you are just reading).

```
    json_value& operator [](std::string key) {
        return object[key];
```

Maybe this is desirable, depends on your use case.

```
    }
};
```

But sometimes you pass by const reference. In this case you can not access members of the object because there is no const access to members. I would a way to accesses elements from a const reference.

```
  json_value const& operator [](std::string key) const {
        auto find object.find(key);
        if (find != object.end()) {
            return find->second;
        }
        // Not sure what you want to do if the object does not exist.
  }
```

---

Not really sure what `json20` is for?

```
class json20 {
```

You don't need it to hold the JSON that is what `json_value` is for. To me this is JSON parsers, which is fine but you don't need to store the json_value inside. Personally I would rename this to JsonParser and then use to read a stream that returns a json_value object.

---

The stream operator `>>` drops all leading white space so you don't actually need to write your own.

```
static void eat_whitespace(std::istream& istrm) {
```

---

Personally I would write eat_whitespace like this:

```
static void eat_whitespace(std::istream& istrm) {

    int ch;
    while (istrm >> ch && std::isspace(ch)) {
        // Do nothing
    }
    if (istrm) {
        istrm.unget();  // We read a non whitespace. Put it back.
    }
}
```

---

So because `operator>>` drops leading white space we can re-write get_next_token

```
static char get_next_token(std::istream& istrm) {
    char ch = static_cast<char>(-1);
    istrm >> ch;  // Don't care if it does not work.
                  // If the read fails then `ch` is unmodified.
                  // So it will have a value of -1.
    return ch;
}
```

---

OK. Streaming:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const json_value& v) {
```

For boolean values we can simplify it:

```
        // IF you want to do it manually.
        os << (std::get<1>(v)) ? "true" : "false";

        // Using the stream operator.
        os << std::boolalpha << std::get<1>(v);
```

---

For objects like the json_object, json_arry and json_null I would write their own stream operators.

```
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, json_array const& v);
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, json_object const& v);
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, json_null const& v);
```

Now you can simplify case 3/4/5:

```
    case 3:  os << std::get<3>(v); break;
    case 4:  os << std::get<4>(v); break;
    case 5:  os << std::get<5>(v); break;
```

---

Lets simplify the `try_string()`

```
static bool try_string(std::istream& istrm, json_value& value) {

    char ch;
    if (istrm >> ch) {
        if (ch != '"') {
            istrm.unget();
            return false;
        }

        std::string s;
        std::getline(istrm, s, '"');
        value.emplace<2>(s);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Pretty sure your try_number does not conform to the JSON standard.

```
static bool try_number(std::istream& istrm, json_value& value) {
```

https://www.json.org/json-en.html

- Your code will read a number with multiple `.` in it.
- Numbers can not start with 0 (unless it is just zero or zero with a fraction).
- You don't support E suffix to numbers.

---

Personally I would convert the C++ code for parsing JSON into LEX code to parse JSON values. The code for lex is a lot simpler:

Comment: Thanks  for the feedback, brilliant.  As for the using json_array = std::vector; I assume you mean using json_array = std::vector<json_value>;  I am struggling with the circular dependency.  I can forward declare struct json_array, but I don't think you can fwd declare using directive?

Comment: The greatest benefit I got from this was: Not really sure what json20 is for?  Absolutely right and I need to switch on my big picture brain!